# How to display this instance method from rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I have two rails models, Usage & Price. So far they look like this:

```
class Usage < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :price

    def spend
        usage.amount * price.amount
    end
end
```

and

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :usage
end
```

I'm trying to call the "spend" by doing this in the console:

```
Usage.create(amount:100)
Price.create(amount:0.1)

usage=Usage.find(1)
puts usage.price
```

Where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the price through the usage model to have the association work.

```
usage = Usage.create(amount:100)
usage.create_price(amount:0.1)
```

Comment: Cheers thanks! If I created the price the way I did it, does this mean that the price I create has no usage associated with it?

Comment: Correct.  Unless you specify usage_id when you create it.  ie: Price.create(usage_id: 1, amount: 0.1)

Comment: Ah. That makes it clearer. I can see how it would work, but unfortunately I'm still getting an error. When I type exactly as you have above, I get the following error: NoMethodError: undefined method "create" for nil:NilClass". This appears after I run usage.price.create, the first one runs fine and adds to the database.

Comment: can you past a gist of the surrounding lines of code and past a link here? https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Sure, https://gist.github.com/lkev/1207c66fe70804b12d12 Thanks for your interest, I'm a complete beginner and have been at this for a number of hours now.

Comment: thats actually my fault :) try usage.create_price(amount: 0.1)

Comment: (Apologies I can't move this to chat as my reputation isn't high enough yet). That's great and it works, but now when I type "puts usage.spend" I get an error! do I need to add another column to my usages table for spend?

Comment: That depends on what you want spend to do.  If you want spend to be a persisted value in the database create a column for it.  If you want spend to modify existing data you can create a model method to do that.

Comment: I actually found the second problem - I should have been referring to "usage" as "self" in the method! Cheers for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

As the price belongs to usage, you should first create the usage object, and then using that you can create the price object.

**usage = Usage.create(amount:100)**

**price = usage.price.create(amount:0.1)**

Then you will get that price related to the usage model.

Then in the usage model you can write,

```
class Usage < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :price

  def spend
    self.amount * (self.price.amount)
  end

end
```

You can call the association like above, `self.price.amount` where "self" is the Usage object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay in two things I was doing. Thanks to blamattina for pointing out this is how you create new associated objects after they've been defined in the model:

```
u = Usage.create(amount:100)
u.create_price(amount:0.1)
```

Also, in the model itself, when referring to the parent class within a model's instance method, the class should be referred to as self:

```
def spend
  self.amount * price.amount
end
```

That last bit was where I was going wrong, and spend can be easily called with u.spend!